# How to break long lines w/ base 64 encoded images in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coding-style, base64, newline

I'm using a **Base 64 encoded image** in my **app_offline.htm file** to display an "upgrade in progress" image when I'm tearing down and rebuilding my Azure-hosted site.

The last time I did this, I used a site that neatly broke lines at **column #77**, and both I and my Visual Studio IDE were happy.

Recently, I used a different site to do the Base 64 encoding, and now I have a string that stretches from **Seattle** to **Rhode Island** on one line.

I've tried all the tricks I can think of to get VS2010 to auto-break this string at or around column #80, but without any luck (like Ctrl+A then Ctrl+K + Ctrl+D).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it yourself with C#: [Convert.ToBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f9a8s97.aspx)  and sample at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.base64formattingoptions.aspx.

Comment: I appreciate this feedback, and working through the sample might be a fun weekend project, but I would still have to write code to read in bytes from an image or set up an array that can be consumed by the sample code. So this is a non-trivial solution, albeit one that would work. However, what I really want is is a native Visual Studio solution or maybe a website that will "pretty format" a base 64 encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

I found a site that lets you specify the number of characters per line for a base 64 encoded string.  Works great.

http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

Now my string only goes from **Seattle** to **Spokane**!

I also learned that **IE8** can only handle **base 64 encodings** that are **under 32K**...which forced me to break apart larger images into small pieces that I then stitched together in the layout. Thankfully, I only need to do this once for my *app_offline.htm* file, and that file is only displayed once or twice a week for 10 to 15 minutes during a teardown / rebuild operation on Azure.